# Unexpected task cancellation behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

I've created a simple .NET Framework 4.7.2 WPF app with two controls - a text box and a button. Here is my code behind:

```cs
private async void StartTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Output.Clear();

    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // Fire and forget
    Task.Run(async () => {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Wait();
            Print("Task delay has been cancelled.");
        }
    });

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Print("Before cancellation.");
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        Print("After cancellation.");
    });
}

private void Print(string message)
{
    var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff");
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        Output.AppendText($"{ time } [{ threadId }] { message }\n");
    });
}
```

After pressing `StartTest` button I see the following results in the `Output` text box:

```
12:05:54.1508 [7] Before cancellation.
12:05:57.2431 [7] Task delay has been cancelled.
12:05:57.2440 [7] After cancellation.
```

My question is why `[7] Task delay has been cancelled.` is executed in the same thread where token cancellation is being requested?

What I would expect to see is `[7] Before cancellation.` followed by `[7] After cancellation.` and then `Task delay has been cancelled.`. Or at least `Task delay has been cancelled.` being executed in another thread.

Note that if I execute `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` from the main thread then the output looks as expected:

```
12:06:59.5583 [1] Before cancellation.
12:06:59.5603 [1] After cancellation.
12:07:02.5998 [5] Task delay has been cancelled.
```

**UPDATE**

Interestingly when I replace

```cs
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

with

```cs
while (true)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

.NET keeps that background thread busy and the output is again as expected:

```
12:08:15.7259 [5] Before cancellation.
12:08:15.7289 [5] After cancellation.
12:08:18.8418 [7] Task delay has been cancelled..
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've updated the code example slightly in the hope to make a bit clearer.

Note that this is not purely hypothetical question but an actual problem I've spent quite some time to understand in our production code. But for the sake of brevity I've created this extremely simplified code example that illustrates the same behaviour.

Comment: Tasks are not threads and async is not parallel,

Comment: `async void Test` should be `async Task Test`. `async void` should be used with event handlers only if you want to be able to handle exceptions from them.

Comment: @MichaelRandall AFAIK by default `TaskScheduler` picks thread from the `ThreadPool` when it needs to run something in "parallel". Hence we see `[1]` and `[5]` in the second output. Nevertheless like I mentioned, even if it decides to run everything on the same background thread, why the order of execution is what it is?

Comment: @Nkosi that was written intentionally to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: @PavelsAhmadulins Noted. Does the same happen when the suggested change is applied?

Comment: @Nkosi returning `Task` from `Test()` method on itself does not change anything unless calling code awaits for it. Anyway for the sake of an experiment I've tested it and as expected it does not change the behaviour.

Comment: *"This behaviour is an issue because if there is some long running operation that runs after delay has been cancelled it blocks"* which delay are we talking about here. The Delay in `StartTest_Click` ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall I've added code excerpt to my UPDATE section to make it clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is why `[7] Task delay has been cancelled.` is executed in the same thread where token cancellation is being requested?

This is because [`await` schedules its task continuations with the `ExecuteSynchronously` flag](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html). I also think this behavior is surprising, and initially reported it as a bug (closed as "by design").

More specifically, `await` captures a context, and *if* that context is compatible with the current context that is completing the task, then the `async` continuation executes directly on the thread that is completing that task.

To step through it:

- Some thread pool thread "7" runs `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`.
- This causes the `CancellationTokenSource` to enter the canceled state and run its callbacks.
- One of those callbacks is internal to `Task.Delay`. That callback is not thread-specific, so it is executed on thread 7.
- This causes the `Task` returned from `Task.Delay` to be canceled. The `await` has scheduled its continuation from a thread pool thread, and *thread pool threads are all considered compatible with each other*, so the `async` continuation is executed directly on thread 7.

As a reminder, thread pool threads are only used when there is code to be run. When you send asynchronous code using `await` to `Task.Run`, it could run the first part (up to the `await`) on one thread and then run another part (after the `await`) on a different thread.

So, since thread pool threads are interchangeable, it's not "wrong" for thread 7 to continue executing the `async` method after the `await`; it's only a problem because now the code after the `Cancel` is blocked on that `async` continuation.

> Note that if I execute cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() from the main thread then the output looks as expected

This is because the UI context is **not** considered compatible with the thread pool context. So when the `Task` returned from `Task.Delay` is canceled, the `await` will see that it's in a UI context and not the thread pool context, so it queues its continuation to the thread pool instead of executing it directly.

> Interestingly when I replace `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), cancellationTokenSource.Token)` with `cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` .NET keeps that background thread busy and the output is again as expected

It's not because the thread is "busy". It's because there's no callback anymore. So the observing method is *polling* instead of being *notified*.

That code sets a timer (via `Task.Delay`) and then returns the thread to the thread pool. When the timer goes off, it grabs a thread from the thread pool and checks if the cancellation token source is cancelled; if not, it sets another timer and returns the thread to the thread pool again. The point of this paragraph is that `Task.Run` doesn't represent just "one thread"; it only has a thread while executing code (i.e., not in an `await`), and the thread can change after any `await`.

---

The general problem of `await` using `ExecuteSynchronously` is normally not an issue unless you're mixing blocking and asynchronous code. In that case, the best solution is to change the blocking code to asynchronous. If you can't do that, then you'll need to be careful how you continue your `async` methods that block after `await`. This is primarily a problem with `TaskCompletionSource<T>` and `CancellationTokenSource`. `TaskCompletionSource<T>` has a nice `RunContinuationsAsynchronously` option that overrides the `ExecuteSynchronously` flag; unfortunately, `CancellationTokenSource` does not; you'd have to queue your `Cancel` calls to the thread pool using `Task.Run`.

Bonus: a [quiz for your teammates](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/d5687f9d11947b7a8e3313c9fb2777bd).

Comment: This is a much better answer and as always i learnt a lot. Ill remove mine, as it seems very lacking

Comment: Thank you, that clarified a lot. I knew that mixing async code with blocking is a code smell but still wanted to fully understand the behaviour of `CancellationToken`.